# NSIS script that can detect Boot Camp running on Mac

Tags: nsis, bootcamp

I've written an NSIS installer that can run on Windows that is running on Boot Camp, running on Mac Pro hardware.  Is there a way my installer can identify that my windows is running under Boot Camp?  I need my installer to behave differently in this situation than it does under windows PCs.   I am already identifying my version of windows via WinVer.nsh, and reading the registry to identify if .NET is installed.  Perhaps there is a registry entry that would give away the Mac platform?  The nsis HwInfo plug-in doesn't appear to provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can natively find out if the user is running Windows on a BootCamp. But you can check if Apple's BootCamp Driver modules are running (tasks), such as:

`AppleOSSMgr Location: C:\windows\system32\appleossmgr.exe`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8uBe.png